# PyGame: Change the starting position of a sprites surface so it doesn't start at (0,0)

Tags: python, pygame

Is there a way to change the starting position of a sprite's surface?

For example, the code below is for a ball sprite. The ellipse is drawn at (50,50) but the surface of the sprite which the drawing is added to begins at (0,0) which means that only part of the ball is shown.

I need the ball sprites surface to start AWAY from the top left corner. Can this be done? If so, how?

My code:

```
class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """
    This class represents the ball.
    """
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)

        pygame.draw.ellipse(self.image, (255,0,0), [50,50,width,height], 10)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Comment: The `rect` argument of `pygame.draw.ellipse` describes the area that the circle will fill; you draw on a white `Surface` and set the color key to white. Why do you start drawing the ellipse at `(50, 50)`? Why not at `(0, 0)`? Why do you need the "wasted" space in the top left if you don't draw anything on it?

Comment: Thanks sloth - I realise my error, the ellipse needs to be drawn at (0,0) as this is being drawn onto the sprite surface. The sprite surface rect coordinates therefore needed to be overwritten. Answer has been left. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Sloths comment struck a chord.
I simply needed to rewrite the sprite's image's rect coordinates to get the surface spawning in a different position. So the ellipse coordinate returned to (0,0) so that it was drawn correctly on the sprite surface and the sprites rect coordinate was overwritten to (50,50):

```
pygame.draw.ellipse(self.image, (255,0,0), [0,0,width,height], 10)

# Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image.
# Update the position of this object by setting the values of rect.x and rect.y

self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
self.rect.y = 50
self.rect.x = 50
```

Comment: You could also use `self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(50, 50))`